how do I change multi dimension custom color on superset?
I understood that I can add json metadata in order to set the colors using things like
"label_colors": {
"A": "#001F3D",
"B": "#002F3D",
"C": "#003F3D",
"D": "#004F3D"
},
However if I have a line chart that is composed of 2 dimensions, saying "Letters" and "Numbers" and that I can have combination likes "A,1" , "A,2", .... how do I do if i want to color only based on letters ?
It appears that I can do it if I list everything like this :
"label_colors": {
"A,1": "#001F3D",
"A,2": "#001F3D",
"B,1": "#002F3D",
...
},
However values from my second field are changing a lot and making a list of these isn't possible.
Is there another way to do this?
Checked a lot of topics talking about label colors, tried multiple things on superset itself

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
